# star rating using for loops

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a star rating system thing where when you hover over it, the stars up to your mouse become orange, then if you move your mouse away, they become black again. [It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYyDH.png). If you click on a stars, the stars up to your mouse should then remain orange, even when you move your mouse away, while the now non-orange stars continue to be affected by whether you hover over them or not. 
This is the code I have written;

```
<div id="stars">
<span id="1" class="fa fa-star" onmouseover="checked('1')" onclick="selected('1')" onmouseout="unchecked('1')"  style="width: 20px;"></span>
<span id="2" class="fa fa-star" onmouseover="checked('2')" onclick="selected('2')" onmouseout="unchecked('2')"  style="width: 20px;"></span>
<span id="3" class="fa fa-star" onmouseover="checked('3')" onclick="selected('3')" onmouseout="unchecked('3')"  style="width: 20px;"></span>
<span id="4" class="fa fa-star" onmouseover="checked('4')" onclick="selected('4')" onmouseout="unchecked('4')"  style="width: 20px;"></span>
<span id="5" class="fa fa-star" onmouseover="checked('5')" onclick="selected('5')" onmouseout="unchecked('5')"  style="width: 20px;"></span>
</div>

<script language="JavaScript" type="application/javascript">

var selectedVariable = false;
var stars = 0;

function checked(x) {
    console.log("Hallo ich bin :"+x);
    var i;
    for (i=1; i<=x; i++) {
        document.getElementById(i).style.color = "orange";
    }
}

function unchecked(x) {
    var i;
    if (selectedVariable==false) {
        for (i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
            document.getElementById(i).style.color = "#305d6d";
        }
    } else if (x>stars) {
        for (i=stars; i<=5; i++) { //why can i not change this to i>stars?
            document.getElementById(i).style.color = "#305d6d";
        }
    }
}

function selected(x) {
    console.log("Clicked :"+x);
    var i;
    for (i=1; i<=x; i++) {
        document.getElementById(i).style.color = "orange";
        stars = x;
    }
    for (i>x; i<=5; i++) {
        document.getElementById(i).style.color = "#305d6d";
    }
    selectedVariable = true;
}

</script>
```

What is happening is that, say i click on the third star, then, from the third star move my mouse away, it works perfectly, meaning the first, second and third stars remain orange. However, if I click on the third star, then move my mouse to the fourth or fifth and *then* move my mouse away, only the first two stars remain orange.
I can see why that is happening, because it makes sense that within the unchecked function it is going to the second else if, where x>stars. 
In order to fix this problem, I would like to change the for loop within that if to for(i>stars; ...) however this then causes the whole thing not to work.

I would like to know why that does not work, since the second for loop in the selected function looks like that and that works, and also how to fix it.

Many thanks :)) this is my first question so, while im sure you wouldn't anyway, please dont hesitate to tell me how to improve it.

Also if this is relevant; I am doing this simply as a learning exercise, so while suggestions to use other languages/systems would be interesting, they will not be particularly helpful.

Comment: I haven't tested your code or thought in detail about the logic, but this for loop in the `selected` function looks wrong: `for (i>x; i<=5; i++)`. The `i>x` there isn't going to do anything, and in particular doesn't set the value of `i` to anything. I think you want `i=x+1` instead.

Comment: Did you try to debug your problem? Learning how to do this is very valuable.

Comment: Oh but that isn't what's causing the issue you mention. Just had a closer look, and the problem you describe is due to this for loop in the `unchecked` function: `for (i=stars; i<=5; i++)`. That first part should be `i=stars+1`. Your current code is explicitly setting all stars above *and including* the selected one to be the original colour. Making the change I suggested will only affect the ones above, as intended.

Comment: I tried that ((i=stars+1; ...))  but then what happens is if i scroll over the remaining stars, they dont switch back after i move my mouse- so they just stay orange. perhaps thats a problem with the other function as you mentioned. thankyou

Comment: i added `(console.log("unchecked :"+x)` within the `for (i=stars+1; i<=5; i++)` and it doesnt show up, although it does if i put it before, also I have now changes the other function to `(i=x+1; i<=5; i++)`

Comment: @RobinZigmond sorry forgot to tag you.

Comment: I've fixed it now but thankyou anyway